# Ordenar en orden alfabético las palabras de una frase

Tags: delphi

Introducir una cadena de caracteres de texto, pulsando la tecla Enter oredanar las palabras en orden alfabético.

Esto es lo que tengo, pero al presionar la tecla Enter no pasa nada, es decir cuando presiona la tecla enter después de escribir la frase no realiza lo que se necesita solo hace un sonido al presionarla.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var s: TStringList;
begin
  if Key = #13 then
    begin
      s:= TStringList.Create;
      s.CommaText:= Edit1.Text;
      s.Sort;
      ListBox1.Items.Text:= s.Text;
      s.Free;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Por favor define "no pasa nada". Veo el código y me parece correcto.

Comment: @Trauma, no es el más popular, pero tampoco está en desuso. Diría que usualmente está dentro del top 10.

Comment: @Neon, es más, lo he probado y funciona correctamente!

Comment: Para evitar el pitido debes asignar `Key := #0;` si procesas tú la tecla, es decir, dentro del bloque `if Key = #13 then begin ... end;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchos años sin usarlo, buenos recuerdos.

En lugar de usar el TKeyPressEvent que estas usando, deberías usar el

`TKeyDownEvent( Sender: TObject, var key: word; shift: TShiftState );`

Según la documentación, `TKeyPressEvent` no sirve para teclas especiales y de control, tal como la tecla `ENTER`. `TKeyDownEvent` es la adecuada para usar en esos casos.

Comment: La tecla enter no es ninguna tecla especial, el enfoque seguido por el OP es correcto para evaluar Enter.

Comment: De la documentación de **Lazarus**, referido a TKeyPressEvent: `This handler only receives characters, not control or other special keycodes. Control keys should be handled by an OnKeyDown handler instead.`

Comment: Lo que te digo es que Enter no es una tecla de control, es una tecla como cualquier otra, que produce el caracter ASCII 13 (decimal), o 0x0D, si prefieres el hexadecimal. Esto no es válido solo para Pascal/Delphi, sino para la generalidad de los casos.

Comment: No soy yo. Es la libreria. Desde que el usuario pulsa una tecla hasta que llega al programa en ejecución, pasa por muchos sitios: hardware->SO->Software de usuario (en este caso, la librería de Pascal o Delphi o lo que sea)->Código del programa (código de Delphi en este caso). ¿ O es que el controlador de teclado del PC genera eventos `TKeyPressEvent` directamente ? ¿ o Windows ? ¿ O el sistema de eventos de Linux ? Además, ASCII 13 es 'Retorno de Carro', no 'Pulsación de tecla ENTER'. Eso es un sinsentido.

Comment: No digo que el controlador del teclado del PC _genere_ eventos, simplemente quise hacer ver que tu respuesta no es correcta, y por qué. De hecho, el enfoque utilizado por el OP es funcional. Un saludo. ;)

Comment: Si, la idea es correcta, esperar a que se pulse la tecla y realizar la acción. Hasta ahí, de acuerdo. Ahora, a partir de ahí ... pues igual divergemos un pelín  xD Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

deberias declarar dos vectores tomando el mismo largo de la palabra usando uno para la palabra, y el otro para ubicarlas por orden que eso al ser valores Hexa ya te reconocera con recorrerlas con un blucle cual es mayor y cual es menor,  y una variable para usar el paso de letras al nuevo array. Espero haberte ayudado con la logica. Saludos

```
palabra as string
palabra= text1 
dim vector1 (len(palabra)) as vector
dim vector2 (len(palabra)) as vector
***cargo vector1 con las letras***


For ID = 1 to (len(palabra)) - 1

    IF vector1(ID) < vector1(ID+1)
        vector2(ID)=vector1(ID+1)
    else
        vector2(ID)=vector1(ID)
    endif
next
```

Espero haber ayudado, saludos

Comment: La respuesta no ataca el problema expuesto por el OP, ni está en Pascal.